# should have come to an end

Tags: modal-verbs

*The authors only regret that they **should have come to an end**. But if we have helped you master a foreign tongue with some success, our task has been worth its while.*

This  is the last paragaph of the epilogue of one of my english textbook. I am not able to understand why "should have come to an end" is used. I know that for example "I should have gone to bed early" means "I didn't go to bed early and now I'm tired". So my sentence means that the authors did not come to an end which is nonsense. Can you explain to me this particular usage in my sentence above.

Comment: **should** there is a modal auxiliary expressing necessity/that which circumstances require/inevitability: "We only regret that they have had to come to an end."

Comment: "master a foreign tongue with some success" is odd.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like this is the author's way of saying goodbye, however it is obviously not written by a native speaker.

You are correct that

> should have come to an end

means "it is *supposed* to end" but has not, and its  bit of nonsense the tha author would *regret* it not ending.  Usually what is written is something like

> The authors only regret *is* that *this must come to an end*.

meaning your "time" or "relationship" with the author is ending.

> our task has been worth its while.

is more usually expressed as

> our task *(of putting this book together)* would have been worth it.

I might question the effectiveness of the book.

Comment: If you search ngram (1700-2000) for `regret that it should have,regret that they should have, regret that we should have,regret that he should have`, and then click on the links at the bottom of the ngram results to reach the attestations, and then peruse those texts, you will find that this is a modal use as I've described in my comment above. It has largely fallen out of use.

Comment: For example: https://books.google.com/books?id=DTJcAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22regret+that+he+should+have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBsNOnuv_TAhVG4iYKHR7lB2sQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22regret%20that%20he%20should%20have%22&f=false

Comment: Or this: https://books.google.com/books?id=Y7JbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA191&dq=%22regret+that+it+should+have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhv-72uv_TAhVFQyYKHShLC-gQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22regret%20that%20it%20should%20have%22&f=false

Comment: I don't think my answer disputes "should" is a modal auxliary. Why the down vote?

Comment: AS a native English speaker, I find the phrasing quite acceptable. Agreed, it is a bit old-fashioned, and a bit formal, but those are qualities appropriate to a farewell. It might be quite a nice book.

Comment: The downvote is because, in this construction, with **regret**, *should have come to an end* doesn't mean  "supposed to end but has not ended". Rather, it means "has had to come to an end".  *After* you have punched a fellow MP in the nose, you can say, "I regret that we should have come to fisticuffs over this, old chap."

Comment: I've never heard that, I've heard "I regret that we have come to fisticuffs over this." or rather since you are using *old chap* "I regret *(that)* it has come to this, *old chap*." would be more a BrE way of expressing it. To express **regret** it would either be "I regret we *should have not* come to fisticuffs" or "I should have been more understanding", implying no punching.  Besides, in the OP's example "regret that they should have come to an end" sounds more like the author is apologizing for an untimely death.